# access wsdl file and display methods and parameters in c#

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, svcutil.exe

Hello I am very new to WCF Services kindly excuse me for wrong terminology. I need to display all the methods in a list and when the method is selected I need to show the parameters so the user can enter the parameter value like id and name so that we can invoke the service and compare the result with expected and actual result.

Note: the user will only provide the WSDL URL, and from there I can generate a dynamic proxy because our services usually change using (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx).

How do I get the operation and parameter types so that we can generate client and invoke service with the parameters. Just want to display methods get the values for parameters from user and invoke the service in a C# windows application.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to use soapUI, which "does this for living"